# Carrierwave rename uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for uploading images. I also have some image cropping that happens later. This process includes sending of the cropped-area dimensions from the client(javascript) and then recreate a cropped image on the server. After this I would like to rename all the version filenames.

Is it possible after the cropping process, I can rename all the various versions. I do not wish to recreate the versions but rather just rename the already existing versions.

Comment: You can use the RMagick-, ImageMagick- or MiniMagick-gem together with CarrierWave to save thumbnails and then rename them as you wish. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite method in your uploader

```
def filename
  "new_name_for_file" if file     
end
```